# find better way to find the text in string contains multi same signs

Tags: python-3.x, regex, search, count

I have below text which each info (text and length) between "|" is different by time , only the number of "|" is fixed. I can retrieve the info i want ("XYZGM")but do we have better way to do ?

```
"@BATCH|ABCDEF|01|12|1||XYZGM|210401113439|online|ATGHDGV03|QGH83826|RevA|||"
```

Current code i used:

```
text="{@BATCH|ABCDEF|01|12|1||XYZGM|210401113439|online|ATGHDGV03|QGH83826|RevA|||"
# get text from 6th position to 7th position of "|"
pos_count=0
z=0
for i in range(z,len(text)):
    pos=text.find('|', z, len(text))
    if pos>0:
        pos_count+=1
        z=pos+1
    if pos_count==6:
        x=pos+1
    if pos_count==7:
        y=pos
        break
print("X: {}, Y: {}".format(x,y))
result=text[x:y]
print(result)
```

and the result is : "XYZGM"

Comment: Perhaps like this `^{@\S*?\|\|([^\s|]+)` using a capture group https://regex101.com/r/pGfpjd/1 Is it always the first value after the double pipe?

Comment: Why not use `result = text.split('|')[6]`?

Comment: Happy my answer worked for you. Please also kindly upvote my answer if you found it helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need using regex:

```py
text="{@BATCH|ABCDEF|01|12|1||XYZGM|210401113439|online|ATGHDGV03|QGH83826|RevA|||"
if text.startswith("{@"):
    print(text[2:].split("|")[6])
```

Make sure there is `{@` text at the beginning, split the rest with `|`, and get the sixth value.

[**Python code**](https://tio.run/##FY3LCoJAFED3foXMatzIPERMCBq1xk2LQqISFy0MB2QUvfSg@@@TnvXhnPEL3WClc9B@YEt@u0xVeYkqy4v9ARlHLpAjXm93fUTBWcQ45zKSGxxsb2yLqtJloS9M4kmXiUxEjOf2pRCReObpr9lwhscE89tAR5cDCVLPXxgnY4GuQi3SJpzH3gAlSII6bgLn/g).

Answer (score 2):

Another option could be using a pattern:

```
^{@(?:[^|]*\|){6}([^|]+)
```

- `^` Start of string
- `{@` Match `{@`
- `(?:[^|]*\|){6}` Repeat 6 times any char except `|` then match `|`
- `([^|]+)` Capture group 1, match 1+ times any char except `|`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oUfKkE/1)

```
import re

pattern = r"^{@(?:[^|]*\|){6}([^|]+)"
s = "{@BATCH|ABCDEF|01|12|1||XYZGM|210401113439|online|ATGHDGV03|QGH83826|RevA|||"

match = re.match(pattern, s)
if match:
    print(match.group(1))
```

Output

```
XYZGM
```